# Make a moving physics body collide with others without being affected itself

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a SpriteKit scene with physics bodies, at some point, I add a sprite and I want a "one way collision" with others : I want them to collide with it but I want it to be unaffected and to continue its trajectory exactly as if it didn't hit anything.

A solution that **partially** works is to affect a really high mass to this physics body so that the collisions on it make negligible changes to its direction and velocity, but unfortunately this causes other objects to bounce really strongly from my object as it carries a lot of energy.

Is there a way to get the behaviour I expect ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to set the `collisonBitMask` of the other body to include the categoryBitMask of the body you want to be unaffected, and then make sure that the `collsionBitMAsk` of the body to be unaffected does NOT include any of the `categoryBitMasks` of the bodies that it is not to be affected by.

It will then happily smash everything out of it's way

Comment: You're welcome. It's worth noting that `contactTestBitMask` does NOT work like this - you only have to set the contactTest bit on one of the bodies for contacts to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Steve Ives' answer is perfect. But I would just like to add that in future if you do need to use a body with much higher mass and don't want other objects to bounce off it at incredible speeds, modify the restitution of the physics body of the object with smaller mass.

The default restitution value is 0.2 and it signifies how much energy is lost after the body collides with another.